# leaflet.draw get height value to geoJSON

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Im using leaflet.js and leaflet.draw to let the user draw a map of a trek. When the user draws a line for the trek it saves only the lat and long values, I saw on other website (that it looks like it uses the same librers) that they are also saving the height value. How can I do it too? The code after user finishes drawing a line:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer,
        feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {};
    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature";
    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    map.removeControl(drawControl);
    $('#uploademap').attr('style', 'display:none;');
    var str = JSON.stringify(drawnItems.toGeoJSON()).toString();
    var hasil = $('#treck_leafletMap').val(str.substring(str.indexOf("coordinates") + 13, str.length - 4));
});
```

Also, In the same website they have height graph on canvas and they get the total clim, descent and distance of the route.
Im useing now to shoe height graph leaflet.heightgraph but i dont want it to appear on the map, I want it on other canvas like the specified website do.
Any idea how to do that?

The code for the leaflet.heightgraph :

```
var hg = L.control.heightgraph();
    hg.addTo(mymap);
    hg.addData(FeatureCollections);
```

Comment: You can add a altitude to the latlng object `L.latlng(49.5,-5.8,2)` [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlng-l-latlng) but leaflet has no data about the altitude so you have to use external services to get it. And when you convert a layer to geojson, the altitude is "converted" into the `coordinates` array

Comment: I'm useing the leaflet.draw to let the user draw the route. This is what you mean by "external services"?

Comment: No you need a servcie who get you the altitude / height of the point. They are named as "elevation"  so search for a `elevation api` and then load for each point the altitude

Comment: Can you give me any example? It feels a little bit to complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call in the `draw:created` event the elevation api to get the altitude for each point of the layer.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer;
    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
    props.attributeType = 0; 
    getAltitude(layer);
...
});
```

Fetch data from the api:

```
function getAltitude(layer){
    if(layer.getLatLngs){
    var urls = [];

    layer.getLatLngs().forEach((ll)=>{
            urls.push('https://APIURL/?points='+ll.lat+','+ll.lng); //No free api!
    })

    Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
            fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
    )).then(json=> {
      var latlngs = [];
      layer.getLatLngs().forEach((ll, idx)=>{
        ll.alt = json[idx].data[0];
        latlngs.push(ll);
      })
      layer.setLatLngs(latlngs);
      console.log(layer.getLatLngs())
        map.fire('dataloaded');
    })
  }else{
    var ll = layer.getLatLng();
    fetch('https://APIURL/?points='+ll.lat+','+ll.lng).then(response => response.json()).then(josn => {
        ll.alt = josn.data[0];
            layer.setLatLng(ll);
        console.log(layer.getLatLng())
        map.fire('dataloaded');
    })
  }
}
```

After getting data, update heightgraph:

```
map.on('dataloaded',(e)=>{
        var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
        geojson.properties = {"Creator": "OpenRouteService.org","records": 36, "summary": "suitability"}; 
        hg.addData([geojson]); 
})
```

Comment: tried applying your idea in this fiddle, doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/hgnLxvk8/7/#&togetherjs=r8S0lT9R1y